# How to Change "via iOS" on native Facebook sharing in IOS6

Tags: ios, facebook

Hi i am using following code to share message using IOS6 native lib

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"Good morning all"];
        //[mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"]];
        [mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
        [self.superViewController presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
        [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            NSString *output = @"";
            switch (result) {
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                    output = @"ACtionCancelled";
                    break;
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                    output = @"Post Successfull";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook Message" message:output delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }];
    }
```

it is successfully posted But in my facebook it is showing via IOS but i want to display my application name. I followed all steps when i am creating app id on facebook developer zone

> How to change IOS to my application name?
>   [image]

I also tried this code http://www.developers-life.com/facebook-compose-view.html

Comment: I think you'd have to use the Facebook iOS sdk for that and not the iOS sdk API

Comment: Thank you for your replay Dear Moxy, I downloaded library from https://developers.facebook.com/ios/ and i run FacebookSDK/Samples/HelloFacebookSample application in IOS6 even though it is showing IOS not my application

Comment: Did you set correct "FacebookAppID" in application plist.

Comment: as @NaveenShan said, you need to create your facebook app, and use your app id.

Comment: Yes i added  appid and urlschema  in plist but no use. Friends have you try this in your 6.0 device or simulator  ever?

Comment: I use it with my iOS 6 device and it works. But I'm using the Facbook 3.0 sdk . I don't know if it changed with 3.1

Comment: Yes it is changed in 3.1 according to IOS 6 compatibility dear

Comment: So guys would you be so kind to explain how to set "via my app" NOT using native sharing? Or it is done automatically when I got access to account ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `SLComposeViewController` you cannot change the "via" name, it will always show "iOS" as the source.

You are required to use the Facebook iOS SDK and set up your own custom compose view instead of using the native SLComposeViewController.

**UPDATE**

Facebook's 3.5+ SDK offers a number of great solutions, such as the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/#sharedialog), which uses the native Facebook and open graph.